# Laravel - Sólo me muestra el árbol de directorios y archivos y no la página Welcome

Tags: laravel

Tras instalar composer y y ejecutar un create-project, me crear los directorios y archivos, pero al entrar en el proyecto localhost/nombreproyecto me muestra el érbol de directorios y archivos.
¿Por qué no me muestra la página Welcome de Laravel?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué sucede?

Un saludo.

Comment: prueba con `localhost/nombreproyecto/public`

Comment: probando localhost/nombreproyecto/public me da el siguiente resultado: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/pruebalaravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 500

Answer (score 2):

Otra solución, en caso de que no quieras crear el vhost para tu proyecto:

- Entra al archivo de configuración de Apache **httpd.conf**.
- Busca la parte donde diga **Document root**
- Sustituye estos valores:
  DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"

  En vez de **/Library/WebServer/Documents**, deberías agregar la ruta de tu proyecto apuntando a la carpeta public, ejemplo:
  **DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/proyecto/public"**

Una vez que hayas hecho esto, escribe **localhost/** en tu navegador y ya deberías poder acceder a tu proyecto.

Espero te ayude, saludos

Comment: A esto le falta solo dos cosillas : 1- sudo apply (nombre fichero.conf) .2- sudo service apache2 restart. Y listo, ya la proxima vez que accedeas a la ip te llevara al index de tu proyecto de laravel

Answer (score 0):

Para poder visualizar tu proyecto desde localhost tienes que crear un archivo de configuración de apache con las re-escrituras de url para que te funcione.
en el directorio /root del proyecto debes crear .htaccess

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Consejo: si deseas ahorrarte de crear estos ficheros puedes optar por instalar Laragon. es un kit de desarrollo web, al crear un proyecto te genera los servidores virtuales para que tu proyecto laravel funcione.

[Laragon Web Oficial](https://laragon.org/)

Comment: ¿Dónde tienes cada proyecto Laravel el directorio /root? ¿Te refieres a routes? Un saludo.

Comment: El root seria el directorio principal del proyecto si usas xampp es  /htdocs/tuproyecto/ pues ahi creas el directorio htaccess con esos parametros

Answer (score 0):

Bastante raro que no te deje acceder como localhost/pruebalaravel/public o 127.0.0.1/prueba... Debe llevarte a la bienvenida.

Primero intenta arreglar eso o haz una instalación limpia y funcional sino lo demás no va funcionarte.

De hecho el que laravel al principio te muestre el directorio de archivos es normal.

Laravel requiere unos cuantos pasos extras para hacer lo que quieres. No es buena idea modificar el .htaccess para eso
(para evitar más complicaciones).

Como parece que estás desarrollando algo nuevo puedes hacer lo siguiente. No sé si uses windows o linux pero estos pasos son globales.

Una manera para acceder directamente al sistema es creando un host virtual.

Suponiendo que quieras acceder a tu proyecto con la url "miproyecto.test" en tu sistema local:

1) Edita tu archivo `hosts` de tu equipo:

- /etc/hosts en linux
- c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts en windows

y agregas al final del archivo lo siguiente:

```
127.0.0.1 miproyecto.test
::1 miproyecto.test
```

2) Ubica tu archivo `httpd-vhosts.etc` de apache (en el panel de xampp debería venir cómo abrirlo) y le agregas esto:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName miproyecto.test
    DocumentRoot a:/xampp/htdocs/miproyecto/public # siempre pon el public
    <Directory  "a:/xampp/htdocs/miproyecto/public"> # igual el public
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

3) Reinicias apache y reinicias navegadores.

**Importante:** Siempre cualquier dirección que pongas siempre debe terminar en ".test",
pues podrías igual poner una dirección tipo miproyecto.com, miproyecto.dev...
pero ni chrome, ni firefox (excepto explorer) te van a permitir acceder a tu proyecto (por seguridad)
y entonces tendrías que habilitar https y configurar muchas cosas más.